# "groups USERNAME" and "getent group" results different outputs

Tags: groups, user-accounts

I found that there is a user named `speech-dispatcher` that belongs to group `audio` (based on `groups speech-dispatcher` output). But it is not listed under `getent group` command! What is the problem?

```
$ getent passwd | grep [s]peech-dispatcher
speech-dispatcher:x:109:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/sh

cat /etc/passwd | grep [s]peech-dispatcher
speech-dispatcher:x:109:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/sh

$ groups speech-dispatcher
speech-dispatcher : audio

getent group | grep [a]udio
audio:x:29:pulse

$ cat /etc/group | grep [a]udio
audio:x:29:pulse
```

Answer (score 2):

The `audio` group is the `speech-dispatcher` user's primary group (as indicated by the GID `29` in `/etc/passwd`, which matches the GID of the `audio` group in `/etc/group`).

Comment: Yes, I know. But `speech-dispatcher` is not listed as a member of `audio` groups under `cat /etc/group | grep [a]udio`. My question is why it is not listed under this command?

Comment: it's not listed because it's not supposed to be listed. `/etc/group` only contains memberships of supplementary groups.  A user's primary group is set in `/etc/passwd`.